# Error when refreshing credentials Cognito Identity

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am trying to authenticate a cognito user pool user in node, but I am running into an error (404) when refreshing the credentials. I try authenticating with `cognitoUser.authenticateUser`. That is successful, and inside the onSuccess, I create credentials with `AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials` and get the following

```
CognitoIdentityCredentials {
expired: true,
expireTime: null,
accessKeyId: undefined,
sessionToken: undefined,
params: 
 { IdentityPoolId: '...',
   Logins: 
    { 'cognito...': '...' } },
data: null,
_identityId: null,
_clientConfig: {} }
```

So I try refreshing the credentials with `AWS.config.credentials.refresh` but I get this error

```
{ UnknownError: Not Found
    at Request.extractError (/Users/.../projects/nodekb/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:48:27)
    at Request.callListeners (/Users/.../projects/nodekb/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)
    at Request.emit (/Users/.../projects/nodekb/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)
    at Request.emit (/Users/.../projects/nodekb/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
    at Request.transition (/Users/.../projects/nodekb/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/Users/.../projects/nodekb/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /Users/.../projects/nodekb/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/.../projects/nodekb/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/.../projects/nodekb/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/Users/.../projects/nodekb/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:115:18)
  message: 'Not Found',
  code: 'UnknownError',
  statusCode: 404,
  time: 2018-02-21T19:03:29.670Z,
  requestId: '...',
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 81.76059666489807 }
```

Note: these are the two libraries I have required

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const AWSCognito = require('amazon-cognito-identity-js');
```

and I'm following the instructions [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-cognito-identity-js). Specifically use case 4

Answer (score 0):

I believe my issue was that my endpoint was set to dynamo. After I changed the endpoint in the AWS configuration, I got another error

Answer (score 0):

```
( < AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials > AWS.config.credentials).refresh((error) => {});
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and always remember that you are not merely solving the problem at hand, but also educating the OP and any future readers of this question and answer. Thus, please [edit] the answer to include an explanation as to why it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, runnining in node, the endpoint was by default set also to dynamodb endpoint. After reseting it (I changed it to undefined), the credentials were refreshed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).